# Android - Downloading image from server and loading into ImageView

Tags: android

Hi I have looked in similar questions, but I could not solve the problem. It is not working.
I am trying to download some images from the server and put them in ImageViews in the android application.

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask {
  protected String doInBackground(String... params)  {
    ...........
    URL urlImagine = new URL("http://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/favicon-vfldLzJxy.ico");
    //Version 1:
    URLConnection conn = urlImagine.openConnection();
    inputStreamImagine = (InputStream)conn.getContent();
    ..........
    //version 2:
    inputStreamImagine = urlImagine.openStream();
    bufImagine = new BufferedInputStream(inputStreamImagine);
    .........
  }
}
    //Some other class:
    .............. 
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569953/download-image-from-image-url-to-image-view
    //version 1:
    //Download Image From Image URL to image view
    if (inputStreamImagine!=null){
      Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStreamImagine);      
      imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    //version 2:
    if (bufImagine!=null){
      // Convert the BufferedInputStream to a Bitmap
      Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufImagine);
      Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bMap);
      imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
      //iv.setImageDrawable(drawable);      
   }
```

I have tried using both examples, but the ImageView is not loading any the image.
Could you please help me?

Comment: Try this example : http://androiddevelopmentworld.blogspot.in/2013/04/how-to-display-image-from-url-in-android.html

Comment: @Prince. Thank you. The example is pretty clear, I am following it, but I don't understand why it is not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use lazy loading concept.You should look over below links:

[Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)

Comment: I am also using the ListView, so I think that you have pinpointed the exact problem that I have. This link is very interesting and probably will lead me to the solution to the problem.

Comment: Yes, sure, I was going to do that, just that I was still working on it. Thank you Himanshu. You helped me a lot. The problem was that they did not load in a ListView.

Comment: Now it is working. Thank you again. I have used Ben Ruijl's answer.

Comment: how to load lazy loading of images and when user click on any image need to display image like view pager

Comment: This does not provide an answer. It is a good idea to give an answer than a mere link.